# SSL Certificate with Incomplete-Chain, passes validation in .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

Using .NET Core 2.2, I need to recreate an incomplete chain SSL error however ServerCertificateValidationCallback gives me a different chain of certificates than I expect, with these certificates passing validation. Can someone explain what is going wrong here?

A standalone test that calls badssl.com:

```
    public void DoTheThing()
    {
        string URI = "https://incomplete-chain.badssl.com";

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
            new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(Validate.ValidateRemoteCertificate);

        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            var output = wc.DownloadString(URI);
        }
    }

    public static bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors policyErrors)
    {
        return policyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None;
    }
```

The X509Chain parameter in my callback contains 3 certificates, ***.badssl.com**, **Digicert** and **Digicert**. Certificate 2 is Digicert and valid.

[image: Visual Studio reports a different 2nd certificate]

However [SslLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=incomplete-chain.badssl.com), it tells me there should be just two certificates, with the 2nd one expired:

[image: SslLabs overview of the incomplete-chain.badssl.com 2nd certificate]

Comment: Check your logic.  Most likely it is return the status that the third certificate is not valid and loosing the fact that the 2nd certificate is valid.

Comment: For expired certificate, you need to use different URL which is: `https://expired.badssl.com/`. URL you are accessing is about incomplete chain which has nothing to do with expired cert. And `https://incomplete-chain.badssl.com` has flawed setup, so can't be reliably tested by most frameworks. The chain will be constructed and the connection will be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET `X509Chain` class has logic to find the missing certificates from ambient system state, which is kicking in here. The only time you'll see an incomplete chain from TLS is when both the server sent an incomplete chain and the system can't fill in the missing pieces.

SslLabs is reporting what happened specifically on the TLS connection.  .NET's `X509Chain` considered the 2nd certificate, decided it made no sense in the chain, and threw it out, so you don't get to see it.  There's no way to see the raw certificate data from the TLS messages via `SslStream`.

Comment: In fact, even if certificate is missing in system, CCE can use AIA extension to retrieve issuer. Actually, it is said on badssl web site.